# Php include to skip the first 12 lines read

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I am reading data from a htm page into a Wordpress post with `<?php include("liveresults/140403F001.htm"); ?>` it works perfectly. I however need to skip the first 12 lines of the html file and only start reading from line 13. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file only contains `HTML` and you don't want to execute it as PHP, then you should not be using `include` anyway. [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is much better suited for that.

However, since you want to ignore the first 12 lines, you should use an [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) which allows you to seek by line:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("liveresults/140403F001.htm");
$file->seek(12);
$file->fpassthru();
```

Note that if your file comes from some sort of external input, you should escape it for HTML, to guard against XSS.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. The problem is the htm is formatted funny, with spaces aligning the data. The script @Paulpro suggests strips all formatting.
It comes out like this:
!(http://www.athleticsnews.co.za/main/results/_Untitled-3.png)
But it should look like this:
!(http://www.athleticsnews.co.za/main/results/_Untitled-4.png)

If I use include it keeps the formatting as it should but does not skip lines.

Comment: @user3315413 It looks like you may be stripping a `<pre>` tag that you should be keeping. I think it would be more helpful to post the "view source" HTML output, than the rendered output.

Comment: you are 100% correct here it is: 
`<html>
<head>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<p>
<pre>
 AllTrax Timing - Contractor License                             2014/04/05 - 2:39 PM
      SA Sub-Youth, Youth, Junior & Under 23 Champs - 2014/04/03 to 2014/04/05
                         Presented by Athletics South Africa                         
                              Coetzenburg, Stellenbosch                              

Event 1  Girls 14-15 100 Meter Sprint`

Comment: @user3315413 One solution could be to just output a `<pre>` tag yourself, before outputting the contents of that file: `?><pre><?php`

Comment: You're probably including some extra invalid HTML however, since that file likely contains a closing `</body>` and `</html>` tag, which you probably include yourself further on. If you want to load it the right way I would recommend taking a look at [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), which would allow you to load that pages and then extract just the `<pre>` element and it's contents.

Comment: Perfect!

`<pre>
<?php $file = new SplFileObject("results/140403F004.htm");
$file->seek(13);
$file->fpassthru();?>`

Does the job!

Comment: @user3315413 Something like: `$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTMLFile("results/140403F004.htm"); $content = $doc->getElementsByTagName('pre')->item(0)->textContent; echo '<pre>', $content, '</pre>';` should also work and will produce valid HTML as well.